# Remove last login message but keep motd in terminal?

Tags: terminal

Does anyone know a way to stop the "last login" message from showing up when I start up the terminal, but still have the MOTD show up?

I tried touch ~/.hushlogin, but that prevented both from showing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are halfway there. Use .hushlogin and add cat /private/etc/motd to the first line of your shell's login rc file.